# iphone google geocoding request failed

Tags: iphone, ios, geocoding

I want to use google geo coding to find a list of place's latitude longitude with name, I have no experience of using this in iphone, but in android it is to just call the url. but when i try the same in iphone it give me error for "Request denied". Guide me how to integrate this in iphone or should I use some library like BSForwardGeocoder, I was doing this

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true", locationString];
url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSURL *wurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSDictionary *dict =  [Json objectWithUrl:wurl];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

and it prints as

```
{
results =     (
);
status = "REQUEST_DENIED";
}
```

Comment: video:- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69ZwR4o7oGQ

Comment: @RaheelSadiq...Check my answer does it work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

```
NSString *locationString = @"1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=true", locationString];
url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSURL *wurl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: wurl];

// Fail to get data from server
if (nil == data) {

    NSLog(@"Error: Fail to get data");
}
else{
    // Parse the json data
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    // Check status of result
    NSString *resultStatus = [json valueForKey:@"status"];

    // If responce is valid
    if ( (nil == error) && [resultStatus isEqualToString:@"OK"] ) {

        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }
}
```

**Reference: [The Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to register for a secret key and have to use it as parameter in the request.

Comment: can u link me to the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",address];
```